# Rendering a VTK unstructured grid with 500k+ cells in ThreeJS / React Three Fiber

Tags: three.js, vtk, react-three-fiber

I have a VTK unstructured grid with 500k+ cells that I would like to render using ThreeJS and React Three Fiber in a performant way.

I would like to be able to view the internal elements of the volumetric mesh (set cell transparency to 50%) not just extract the exterior surface.

The grid is mainly comprised of Hexahedrons, tetrahedrons and quadrilaterals. Here is simple example of the file format (This is just 2 hex, 2 tet and 1 quad for brevity):

```
# vtk DataFile Version 2.0
Two hexahedrons with two tetrahedrons and one quadrilateral face
ASCII
DATASET UNSTRUCTURED_GRID
POINTS 13 float
0 0 0
0 0 0.5
0.5 0 0.5
0.5 0 0
0 0.5 0
0 0.5 0.5
0.5 0.5 0.5
0.5 0.5 0
0 0 1
0.5 0 1
0 0.5 1
0.5 0.5 1
0.5 1 0.5

CELLS 5 33
8 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
8 1 8 9 2 5 10 11 6
4 4 5 6 12
4 5 10 6 12
4 0 8 10 4

CELL_TYPES 5
12
12
10
10
9
```

Here is an example of a mesh being sliced / showing the internal elements:
[image: Mesh slice]

I am able to extract the vertices and separate the cells into quads, hex and tets.

I have tried rendering the grid using basic ThreeJS geometries, but the performance is not satisfactory. I would like to know if there's a more performant way to render such a large number of cells in ThreeJS / React Three Fiber.

Is this a job for a shader? Can a shader render each cell independently to create the volumetric mesh if so how on earth is that done?

If using a BufferGeometry is there a way to change the indices array to account for quads, hex and tets?

Little bit lost so any help, tips or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This type of mesh behavior is pretty non-standard, so there’s no out-of-the-box way for Threejs to do this type of rendering for you. What you’re describing sounds very advanced, and not possible without being knowledgeable in writing custom shaders, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will get to learning shaders then!